# Computed property with a subscripted struct

Tags: swift, subscript, computed-properties

I have a `struct ExampleStruct` with a custom `subscript`. The struct data are a fixed private dictionary, `value`. The structure has one element `Sum` that is essentially a summation of the the other elements in private dictionary

```swift
struct ExampleStruct {
   private var value: [String:Double] {
     didSet {
     value["Sum"] = value.filter{$0.key != "Sum"}.reduce(0.+)
     }
   }

   init(){
      value = ["Ind1":12, "Ind2":13, "Sum":25]
   }
   subscript(index: String) -> Double {
     get {
// some error checking too about index
       return value[index]
     }
     set {
       value[index] = newValue
     }
```

I want to use this struct as a computed property that depends on another function which depends on the value of the struct with the "Sum" index through another dependent function.  sampleFunc is something like:

```
func sampleFunc() -> ExampleStruct {
...
     sampleFunc2(sum: exampleImplementation["Sum"])
...
}
```

I was using the following but it was recursive:

```
var exampleImplementation: ExampleStruct {  
     return sampleFunc()   //sampleFunc depends on exampleImplementation["Sum"]
                     //func returns ExampleStruct   
   }
}
```

But I only need the function to set the indices other than "Sum".  So I want something like:

```swift
var exampleImplementation: ExampleStruct {  
   if INDEX=="SUM" {   //
      return SOME BACKING VALUE 
   } else {
     return sampleFunc()[INDEX NOT EQUAL TO "Sum"]   //func depends on exampleImplementation["Sum"]
                     //func returns ExampleStruct   
   }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this for a struct that has a subscript in a computed property?

Comment: That struct won’t compile and what exactly is it your computed property is supposed to return?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question more? I don't follow. What's `ExampleImplemenation`? It is a computed property inside `ExampleStruct`, which returns an `ExampleStruct`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do, Do you want to return the value/Double or an ExampleStruct? if you want the ExampleStruct and not the Double?

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer and clean up the sample code.   It definitely compiles, but because of the (hidden) dependence on exampleImplementation["Sum"] it is recursive.   
exampleImplementation is an instance of ExampleStruct.  It is computed based on another func which returns the type ExampleStruct.

Comment: "It definitely compiles", it definitely does _not_ compile.

Comment: By "It definitely compiles", I meant my original code with the same basic logic compiled, BUT, it had the recursive loop that was crashing at runtime.  The compiling wasn't my problem, the recursive loop was.  
Either way, the solution you provided is very nice.  I still think it leaves a recursive loop, because the exampleImplementation property still calls the sampleFunc for the "Sum" index, which enters the loop. Regardless, this is a much more elegant implementation of the idea of the struct.  I worked around the issue with a backing property but it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the inconsistent code isn't the solution simply to add a filter to the `set` part of the `subscript` method?

```
set {
    if index == "Sum" { return }
    value[index] = newValue
}
```

My edition of the complete struct

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    static let Sum = "Sum"
    private var value: [String:Double] {
        didSet {
            value[Self.Sum] = value.filter{$0.key != Self.Sum}.map(\.value).reduce(0 , +)
        }
    }

    init(){
        value = ["Ind1":12, "Ind2":13, "Sum":25]
    }
    subscript(index: String) -> Double? {
        get {
            value[index]
        }
        set {
            if index == Self.Sum { return }
            value[index] = newValue
        }
    }

    var sum: Double {
        value[Self.Sum, default: 0]
    }
}
```

An example

```
var example = ExampleStruct()

example["Ind1"] = 3
example["Ind2"] = 3
example["Ind3"] = 3
example[ExampleStruct.Sum] = 3
print(example.sum)
```

> 9.0